# “500: Unknown web method” when i send data using $.ajax and WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to send data via Ajax to my database, using the JQuery Ajax function and
and WebMethod in my C# code.  But it's not working.  Any ideas?

```
$(function() {
    $('#Add').click(function() {
        var $dialog = $('<div id="MyDialog"></div').appendTo('body')
            .load("../Pop-up.aspx #pop-up", createDatePicker)
            .dialog({
                position: 'center',
                width: 550,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function() {
                        var jname = $('#name').val();
                        var jbirthday = $('#datepicker').val();
                        var jgender = $('input:radio[name=Gender]:checked').val();
                        var jcourseId = $('#DropDownList1').val();
                        var myjson = {
                            name: jname,
                            birthday: jbirthday,
                            gender: jgender,
                            courseId: jcourseId
                        };

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "Manage.aspx/AddStudent",
                            data: $.toJSON(myjson)
                        });
                    },
                    "Cancel": function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        return false;
    });

});
```

and this is my web method

```
      [WebMethod]
      public static void AddStudent(string birthday,string name,string gender,string courseId)
      {
        var repository = new StudentRepository();
        var student = new Student
                            {
                                Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(birthday),
                                Name = name,
                                Gender = gender,
                                Course_ID = Convert.ToInt32(courseId)
                            };
        repository.InsertStudent(student);
            repository.Save();
      }
```

Comment: "some thing wrong" and "it's not work" is hardly what I'd call a "descriptive post." You'll need to do much, much better than that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was causing your error and how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of the properties on your JSON object so they match the parameters in your Webmethod.

```
    var myjson = {
       birthday: jbirthday, //now the properties match the parameters
       name: jname,
       gender: jgender,
       courseId: jcourseId
    };

    public static void AddStudent(string birthday, string name, string gender, 
        string courseId)
    { ... }
```

I think you're seeing the 500 error because ASP.NET can't find a method signature that matches your deserialized JSON object, even though all the parameters are of type string.

**Update**

I've had a chance to test out what I originally suggested, and the ordering of properties didn't matter.

Not sure if any of this helps but, I saw 500 errors when:

- The properties on my JSON object didn't match all the parameters in my WebMethod

  ```
  var myjson = {b: 'test1', c: 'test' };

  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
  public static void TestMethod(string a, string b)
  { 
      //does nothing.
  }
  ```
- One of the parameters I was passing in was undefined.

  ```
  var myjson = {a: undefined, b: 'test' };

  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
  public static void TestMethod(string a, string b)
  { 
      //does nothing.
  }
  ```

Comment: Also jgender is undefined, he has only defined jgander.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
data: JSON.stringify(myjson)
```

instead of:

```
data: $.toJSON(myjson)
```